# ASP.NET model containing date that's generated automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a model like this

```
public class RaidRequest
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Permissions Access { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Group UserOrAdmin { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Department { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string NameSurname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UNCPath { get; set; }

}
```

I would like to have a Date followed by -1, -2, -3 if there are more requests made that day, and is it possible to make it automatic? for example if there are more than one it says:

> 06022020-1
>
> 06022020-2
>
> 06022020-3

and so on.
But if there is only one made that day it would just say

> 05022020-1
>
> 06022020-1

something like this.

Comment: Okay, you stated a goal. What's preventing you from accomplishing that goal? What problem are you actually facing?

Comment: I have no idea on what to start

Comment: Break your task down into smaller tasks. You need to figure out the current date. Do you know how to do that? Then great. Then you need to figure out how to calculate the sequence number. I can think of two strategies: query existing requests, and find out the max sequence number for the current date, and then increment it by 1. Or use some sort of storage that automatically increments every time it's accessed, and then reset it back to 1 every day. There's probably other ways. The point is: you need to take it upon yourself to plan and then implement your plan. Stack Overflow isn't for that.

Comment: okay. some parts of this i can do. but where to put the DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") in the model? `{ get; set; }` this doesn't allow me to put anything in between.

Comment: something like public string DateWithIndex {get { return System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + Id;}}

Comment: Probably a better name would be RaidName or RequestName or Name.

Comment: @yob The Id isn't the right field to use. The Id will presumably be completely unique. It would be better to calculate the value outside the model, and only store the resulting string within the model.

Comment: @mason, - yes, i was trying to show where to start

Comment: Okay guys. thanks for the start. now I have to figure out what to use instead of Id.

Comment: Just make sure you're prepared for concurrent requests - e.g. in the case where two submissions happen at the same second. One easy way out is to use something like GUID. Another is to have your database generate the IDs for you safely (assuming you use a DB that has locking).

Comment: The multiple requests wont be a problem. the system is used once or twice per day at most. @Code Slinger . I have a new problem. Now the request name changes every day. how can i get it to stay in the database? because yesterday it said 06022020-69 but now (the next day) its saying 07022020-69

Comment: @Renārs  - because you initialize your field with today's date when you populate your instance, instead of setting with the value from the database?